# How to check an ASP.NET MVC user is authenticated and authorized from a separate WCF service application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-identity-2

I have two projects:

1. An ASP.NET MVC 5.2 Application using ASP.NET Identity 2.2
2. A WCF Application SOAP XML service.

Note:  The WCF service is not hosted by ASP.NET, nor is it running in ASP.NET compatibility mode.  A requirement of this project is that it is interface based and ASP.NET compatibility mode does not appear to allow an interface based implementation.

The ASP.NET MVC Application calls the WCF SOAP XML service server side when a user makes a specific action request.  However, the WCF service is accessed via the public Internet so in theory anyone could call it if they knew the address.  I need to ensure that only ASP.NET Identity registered users who are Administrator role are able to call it.  The WCF Application could directly access the database but it doesn't seem like it would be the best solution?

How can I check from the WCF service whether a user is authenticated and authorized in ASP.NET MVC 5.2 using ASP.NET Identity 2.2 using object passing?  Which objects or properties should be passed and checked?  Is there any other solution?  Is it possible to check authentication/authorization with attributes in wcf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you own both, are they in the same domain?

You could interact with a database behind the scenes to generate an auth token, then have the wcf service pass a url with the token back to the user. When the user goes to the site via the tokenized url it checks against the database from the perspective of the ASP app and authenticates. It's a bit asymmetric, but it would handle your use case without getting into domain restrictions.